# Reading DataMatrix with AVFoundation

Tags: swift, avfoundation, qr-code, datamatrix

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547541/scanning-barcode-or-qr-code-in-swift-3-0-using-avfoundation) works with standard QR Codes, but however not with a Data Matrix like [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Datamatrix.svg/220px-Datamatrix.svg.png).

Comment: The reason for this is, that your example doesn't scan for Data Matrix. It only scans for AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code and AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code. 

It should work, if you add `AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode`to the `metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes`-array.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot! Now it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is, that your example doesn't scan for Data Matrix. It only scans for `AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode`, `AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code`, `AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code` and `AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code`. It should work, if you add `AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode` to the `metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes`-array.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmetadatamachinereadablecodeobject/machine_readable_object_types) you find a list of the machine readable object types you can scan for with AVFoudation.