# AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate not called in swift 4 for QR scanner

Tags: qr-code, ios11, swift4

I was working on QR code scanner app on iOS where i was getting output `AVCaptureOutput` on the delegate method `captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:`.

It was working perfectly on swift 3. After I've updated to xcode 9 and swift 4, it stopped working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay I've found an update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547541/scanning-barcode-or-qr-code-in-swift-3-0-using-avfoundation#46546821).

Found that `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` method is changed

from

```
captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

to

```
metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

After changing this delegate method, its working good now.

Comment: Note that the signature of this method changed (again..) after converting to Swift 4 - and it is not detected / fixed by the automatic migration - unlike other camera related callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for this! What's bizarre is that the compiler did not complain that I was missing the protocol's function implementation because the function is marked `optional`. Considering this is the only method in this protocol to implement, I do not think it should be `optional`.

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 4:

Replace

```
let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
```

With:

```
let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.upce,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39Mod43,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean8,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.aztec,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.pdf417,
                          AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes
```