# Replacement of Zbar SDK for IOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

I have an old IOS project 
in that developer used ZbarSDK.
Because of some issues we have to stop the development of the project, 
but now we are starting the project again.
The issue we are facing now is ZBAR doesnt support IOS 11.
So can any one can tell me how to resolve this issue 
or any other free efficient SDK to replace ZBAR ?

Comment: Use AVFoundation's barcode scanning abilities. [Here is an example code that you can use.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546821/3151675)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zbar with Bitcode and 64-bit support has been recompiled and is available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-ziC02v2vGiTENJWGdacXVxUEE

Zbar provides support for many more barcode types than `AVFoundation` does.